# Blazor WASM: Add JWT auth with custom API

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have built an API that controls some smart home stuff. To prevent the whole internet from doing so, I added authentication using JWT / Bearer. The API contains endpoints for the smart home stuff aswell as some user management:
[API endpoints for users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi5TH.png)

The login will return a JWT token if credentials were valid. It is also built using .NET 6:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
        };
    });
```

Login Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLogin login)
{
    var user = await _userService.GetUser(login.Username);
    if (user is not null && _userService.IsPasswordCorrect(user, login.Password))
    {
        var tokens = await _userService.GetJwtAndRefreshToken(user);
        return Ok(new LoginResponse { JWT = tokens.Jwt, RefreshToken = tokens.Refreshtoken });
    }
    return Unauthorized("Wrong username or password!");
}
```

Now I am trying to build a frontend for this app using blazor. When creating the app, i used the option "individual user accounts" for authentication. It is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

This created the following in the blazow WASM app:

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    // Configure your authentication provider options here.
    // For more information, see https://aka.ms/blazor-standalone-auth
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
});

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://localhost:7110/login",
    "ClientId": "33333333-3333-3333-33333333333333333"
  }
}
```

I changed the Authority to my login api url, but doesn't seem to be enough.
Clicking on the login button that was added by default fires this request:
[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FPzx.png)

Is there a simple way to use the MS Authorization framework with my custom api?

Comment: OIDC is for oauth, you just need to request a token from your API using http client, your probably better of using hosted wasm if u have a .net api anyway. as you'll have cross origin issues

Comment: @fuzzybear yea, maybe it would make sense to switch to the hosted WASM. The thing is, I wanted to stay in the .NET Authorize framework, so I can also use the attributes etc. on the WASM side. Therefore, requesting my token and always sending it with the requests isn't enough :)

Comment: Hi, the api is exactly the same asp.net core, the wasm client is just 'hosted' for you

Comment: your other option is to use YARP I've tried both, YARP is great I might switch back, but for development it's a lot easier using hosted

Answer (score 1):

I spent great amount of time on this. These are my notes from it. Note that I am using IdentityServer. Probably a lot of stuff will be different for you. But it should at least guide you what to check.

It works (for me), but best-practise is not garantee.

My API address is on port `5001`, Client is on port `5101`

**For Client project**

- Change HttpClient address in Client. Change Http MessageHandler. Change address for public client

```cs
var clientBaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["apiurl"] ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("apirul is null (reading from config file)"));

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BlazorApp6.ServerAPI", client =>client.BaseAddress = clientBaseAddress)
         .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
         {//this is need when api is separated. https://code-maze.com/using-access-token-with-blazor-webassembly-httpclient/
             var handler = sp.GetService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()!
             .ConfigureHandler(
                 authorizedUrls: new[] { builder.Configuration["HttpMessageHandlerAuthorizedUrls"] },
                 scopes: new[] { "BlazorApp6.ServerAPI" }
              );
             return handler;
         });
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<PublicClient>(client => client.BaseAddress = clientBaseAddress);
```

- Add `HttpMessageHandlerAuthorizedUrls` `apiurl` to appsettings (example for developement):

  ```json
  "apiurl": "https://localhost:5001",
  "HttpMessageHandlerAuthorizedUrls": "https://localhost:5001",
  ```
- Program.cs AddApiAuthorization is different (set  opt.ProviderOptions.ConfigurationEndpoint)

  ```cs
  builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(
  //this line is only when address of api consumer is different 
  opt => opt.ProviderOptions.ConfigurationEndpoint = builder.Configuration["ApiAuthorizationConfigurationEndpoint"]
    ).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserFactory>();
  ```
- Add `ApiAuthorizationConfigurationEndpoint` to appsettings

  ```json
  "ApiAuthorizationConfigurationEndpoint": "https://localhost:5001/_configuration/BlazorApp6.Client"
  ```
- Change launchSetting to different port

  ```json
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5101;http://localhost:5100",
  ```

**For api project**

- Add cors to client app

  ```cs
  string developmentCorsPolicy = "dev_cors";
  services.AddCors(opt =>
  {
    opt.AddPolicy(name: developmentCorsPolicy, builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5101", "https://localhost:5201")
        .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
  });
  //...
  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
      app.UseCors(developmentCorsPolicy);
  ```
- There is probably some need to add cors for identiy server, [but it works without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718515/cors-request-was-ignored-because-path-was-not-for-an-allowed-identityserver-cors).

  - in case it is needed:

    ```cs
    services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>((container) =>
    {
    var logger = container.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>>();
    return new DefaultCorsPolicyService(logger)
    {
        AllowAll = true
    };
    });
    ```
- Change appsettings IdentityServer section to have some info about client.

  - This info is obtained in OidcController with requests starting _configuration:

    ```json
      "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "BlazorApp6.Client": {
        "Profile": "SPA",
        "LogoutUri": "https://localhost:5101/authentication/logout-callback",
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5101/authentication/login-callback"
      },
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Development"
      } }
    ```
  - Note that Profile has changed to SPA (instead of IdentityServerSPA, which means hosted)